# preprocessing for database and decision tree modeling with python

Tags: python

I have a database with 45,212 observations, and I want to perform decision tree modeling for this database using Python. My issue lies in the preprocessing steps. When I input the code, my dataset ends up significantly reduced to just 5 rows, and I find this illogical for machine learning modeling. How can I handle preprocessing without losing a substantial amount of data in the context of decision tree modeling?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Charger le DataFrame initial
# Assurez-vous d'avoir importé vos données correctement avant d'exécuter ce code
# df = ...

# Remplacer les 'unknown' par NaN dans les colonnes catégorielles
df.replace('unknown', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Imputation des valeurs manquantes avec la médiane pour les variables numériques et le mode pour les variables catégorielles
numeric_columns = ['age', 'balance', 'day', 'duration', 'campaign', 'pdays', 'previous']
categorical_columns = ['job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan', 'contact', 'month', 'poutcome']

numeric_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
categorical_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')

df[numeric_columns] = numeric_imputer.fit_transform(df[numeric_columns])
df[categorical_columns] = categorical_imputer.fit_transform(df[categorical_columns])

# Encodage One-Hot pour les variables catégorielles
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_columns, drop_first=True)

# Normalisation/Standardisation des caractéristiques numériques
scaler = StandardScaler()
df_encoded[numeric_columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df_encoded[numeric_columns])

# Séparation des données en ensembles d'entraînement et de test
X = df_encoded.drop('Target', axis=1)
y = df_encoded['Target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Votre jeu de données est maintenant prêt pour être utilisé dans un modèle d'apprentissage automatique
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Charger le DataFrame initial
# Assurez-vous d'avoir importé vos données correctement avant d'exécuter ce code
# df = ...

# Remplacer les 'unknown' par NaN dans les colonnes catégorielles
df.replace('unknown', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Imputation des valeurs manquantes avec la médiane pour les variables numériques et le mode pour les variables catégorielles
numeric_columns = ['age', 'balance', 'day', 'duration', 'campaign', 'pdays', 'previous']
categorical_columns = ['job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan', 'contact', 'month', 'poutcome']

numeric_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
categorical_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')

df[numeric_columns] = numeric_imputer.fit_transform(df[numeric_columns])
df[categorical_columns] = categorical_imputer.fit_transform(df[categorical_columns])

# Encodage One-Hot pour les variables catégorielles
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_columns, drop_first=True)

# Normalisation/Standardisation des caractéristiques numériques
scaler = StandardScaler()
df_encoded[numeric_columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df_encoded[numeric_columns])

# Séparation des données en ensembles d'entraînement et de test
X = df_encoded.drop('Target', axis=1)
y = df_encoded['Target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Votre jeu de données est maintenant prêt pour être utilisé dans un modèle d'apprentissage automatique
```

Comment: Maybe it would help to print out the shape of your dataframe after each step and make sure it corresponds to what you think should be happening. Also doing it on a subset of data — say ten rows also might help. That will help you understand where things are going wrong. I don't see anything in the code that explains it on first glance.

Comment: Do you have the same code here included twice? Might be easier for people to read if you remove the redundant copy.

Comment: Could you please help me with the necessary preprocessing steps for this dataset:

i think that it is mistake mabe in my comands